# why sub-process module does not execute multiple commands in a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, subprocess

I have a list of IP addresses saved in a text file and I want to check they code number (404, 200, 504, ...) using sub-process module and a for loop. for one IP address my code works fine but when I try a list contains more than one IP it gives me some errors.

Here is my text file :

```
77.87.19.114
143.21.15.91
17.63.33.21
24.44.12.181
```

the code I use :

```
from subprocess import check_output

def ipcheck200(ip_list_file):
   with open(ip_list_file) as f:
      content = f.readlines()
   for item in content:

    # url generator for each ip
       url = "http://" + item + "/"
    #print(content[0])

    # command generator for each ip
       command = "python -c " + '"'
       command += "import urllib ;"
       command += "a = urllib.urlopen('%s') ;print(a.getcode())" % url
       command += '"'
       proc = check_output(command)
       print(proc)
```

the result will be :

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    ipcheck200('test.txt')
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\file.py", line 17, in ipcheck200
    proc = check_output(command)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
CalledProcessError: Command 'python -c "import urllib ;a = urllib.urlopen('http://77.87.19.114
/') ;print(a.getcode())"' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Comment: There's a space at the end of your URL, just before the `/` (`http://77.87.19.114 /`), is it normal?
Check the input.

Comment: What happens without the for loop?

Comment: @Morb yes It's OK, I just checked.

Comment: The items will have a newline on the end and you don't strip them off.

Comment: @PeterWood my main program has more than 10,000 IP addresses to check. what is the better way in your opinion ?

Comment: @PythonDeveloperDummy Does it work with just one value? Maybe the `for` loop isn't the problem.

Comment: @PeterWood yeah I tried it with only the first value, the result is : 200

Comment: Can you post the code which works and the code which doesn't? Did you get the single IP value from the file, or just hard code it?

Comment: @PeterWood there is no difference between the codes. the difference is in text file which contains IP addresses. if you put only one IP address it will work fine; but if you place more than one, errors appear.

Comment: @PythonDeveloperDummy If you have more than one in your file you have a newline which needs stripping off the end before saying `url = "http://" + item + "/"`.

Comment: @PeterWood yes you're right. I edited the code the result is not looks good! [0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: Why do you have a Python script using shell to call another Python script? Just invoke the function directly?

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet I tried it before. I think as MartijnPieters said the problem is exception handling. my codes work fine in python shell but when I want to do it directly it fails! if you have any idea about it I would be happy by sharing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python exits with `1` when there is an unhandled exception.

You have no error handling; if a IP address doesn't exist, contains extra whitespace or even if a machine refuses a connection or simply times out, `urllib.urlopen()` will raise an exception:

```
>>> urllib.urlopen('http://127.0.0.1:80')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 213, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 350, in open_http
    h.endheaders(data)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1053, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 897, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 859, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 836, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 575, in create_connection
    raise err
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

Your code takes lines from the file without further processing; it'll have a newline attached to each line, at the very least, so you'd want to *strip* the line:

```
for item in content:
    item = item.strip()
```

You are also executing all the subprocesses in *sequence*, because `check_output()` waits for the process to complete first; this is going to be slower than trying to run this code in the same process. Don't re-invent the multi-processing wheel here, use the [`multiprocessing` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) instead:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import urllib

def check(ipaddress):
     try:
         response = urllib.urlopen('http://{}/'.format(url))
     except IOError:
         return 0  # connection unsuccessful (timeout, connection refused, etc)
     return response.getcode()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(10)
    with open(ip_list_file) as f:
        ipaddresses = [address.strip() for address in f if address.strip()]
    print(p.map(check, ipaddresses))
```

This sample will use 10 subprocesses to test ip addresses in parallel.

Comment: what about result ? for me result is [0, 0, 0, 0]. but I'm sure first IP address is OK.

Comment: @PythonDeveloperDummy: then you still get exceptions. Are you sure that those IP addresses are reachable on port 80? Try to add logging (where you log the `repr()` of each ip address you try to access), and log any exceptions you get too.

Comment: @PythonDeveloperDummy: can you *please* make up your mind about wether or not my answer is helpful to you? I'm feeling a bit like a yo-yo here. If you have follow-up problems implementing your solution, perhaps you need to ask additional questions, but please consider if the general approach and advice offered here is helpful or not, independent of your own implementation. *Then* mark the answer or not, and move on.

Comment: @ MartijnPieters I'll check it out as soon as possible.

Comment: Use `f('http://%s/'  % url)` instead of `f('http://%s/') % url` @Merzhaak it may fix the `[0, 0, 0, 0]` result.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: ugh, see, I knew I should have paid more attention to that little detail when the suggested edit came in :-(